# Node JS dosen't update date picker from Mongo DB

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I want to update certain fields in Node JS and I get value for all string fields.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IGIm.png)
But I cant get display value in date picker control. When I inspect element I get that value in value field of HTML.

Something. I didnt find answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment js libary  https://momentjs.com

- and the solution will be

```
// you can enter the value of the date in the moment(value from mongodb) function
moment("2012-11-22T12:54:43.852Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```